# Trying to add an external Score File to a Python Guessing Game

Tags: python, text-files

I'm creating a Python guessing game for school.
The game its self works fine, but I need to add an external score file (.txt)
I've tried a lot of different ways to implement this but where I'm having trouble is;
If the userName is existing in the file, how do I update that userName's score line.

The last method (in the code) was just a test to have a new userName added to the file if it was not found. This seemed to have over written the file, without adding the new userName.

```
# Import random library
import random
import os

# Welcome User to the game
print("Welcome to the game")

# Collect user details
userName = input("Please enter your Name: ")

# Roll the die for the number of guesses
print("Rolling the Dice!")
diceRoll = random.randint(1,6)
print("You have %d Guesses: " %diceRoll)

# Random picks the number to guess
number = random.randint(1,99)

guesses = 0
win = 0
lose = 0

# Loop checks the users input against the randint and supplies a hint, or breaks if correct
while guesses < diceRoll:
    guess = int(input("Enter a number from 0 to 99: "))
    guesses += 1
    print("This is guess %d " %guesses)

    if guess > 100:
        print("Number out of range. Lose a turn")

    if guess < number:
        print("You guessed to low")

    elif guess > number:
        print("you guessed to high")

    elif guess == number:
        guesses = str(guesses)
        print("You Win! you guessed the right number in",guesses + " turns")
        win = +1
        break

# If the user cannot guess the number in time, they receive a message    
if guess !=number:
    number = str(number)
    print("You Lose. The number was: ",number)
    lose = +1

with open('scoreList.txt', 'r') as scoreRead:
    with open('scoreList.txt', 'w') as scoreWrite:
        data = scoreRead.readlines()
    for line in data:
        if userName not in line:
            scoreWrite.write(userName + "\n")
    scoreRead.close()
    scoreWrite.close()
```

It doesn't matter so much what the formatting of the score file looks like, as long as I can edit existing scores when they enter their name at the start of the game. Add a new user if it doesn't exist. Then print the scores at the end of each game.

I'm at a complete loss.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple mistakes in your final block. You open `scoreList.txt` but do the write operations outside of the `with .. as` block. Outside this block, the file is closed. Also because you are using `with .. as`, you don't have to close the files manually in the end.

And then, you iterate over all lines and would write the name for each line, that does not contain it, so potentially many times. And you open the file with `'w'`, telling it to overwrite. If you want to append, use `'a'`.

Try it like this:

```
with open('scoreList.txt', 'r') as scoreRead:
    data = scoreRead.readlines()
with open('scoreList.txt', 'a') as scoreWrite:
    if userName + "\n" not in data:
        scoreWrite.write(userName + "\n")
```

Also note, that you are currently writing each name into the score list and not only those, that won the game.

Comment: Haha thanks mate. Yeah I ended up redoing that whole block completely using append. No file close and a single with open instead of the two. This whole thing drove me nuts for a while

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can accomplish this using the json module, as it will allow the use of data from a dictionary in the JSON file format.

A dictionary would be the superior method to storing users and associated scores, because it is easier to access these values in python, if using an associated text file.

I have updated your code with a working solution:

```
#! usr/bin/python

# Import random library
import random
import os
import json

# Welcome User to the game
print("Welcome to the game")

# Collect user details
userName = input("Please enter your Name: ")

#Added section
current_player = {"name": userName,
                    "wins": 0,
                    "losses": 0,
                    }

try:
    with open('scores.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    for i in data['players']:
        if i["name"] == current_player["name"]:
            current_player["wins"] = i["wins"]
            current_player["losses"] = i["losses"] 
except:
    pass

print(current_player)
#end added section

"""begin game"""
# Roll the die for the number of guesses
print("Rolling the Dice!")
diceRoll = random.randint(1,6)
print("You have %d Guesses: " %diceRoll)

# Random picks the number to guess
number = random.randint(1,99)

guesses = 0
win = 0
lose = 0

# Loop checks the users input against the randint and supplies a hint, or breaks if correct
while guesses < diceRoll:
    guess = int(input("Enter a number from 0 to 99: "))
    guesses += 1
    print("This is guess %d " %guesses)

    if guess > 100:
        print("Number out of range. Lose a turn")

    if guess < number:
        print("You guessed to low")

    elif guess > number:
        print("you guessed to high")

    elif guess == number:
        guesses = str(guesses)
        print("You Win! you guessed the right number in", guesses + " turns")
        win = +1
        break

# If the user cannot guess the number in time, they receive a message    
if guess !=number:
    number = str(number)
    print("You Lose. The number was: ", number)
    lose = +1
"""end game"""

#added section
current_player["wins"] += win
current_player["losses"] += lose

try:
    for i in data['players']:
        if current_player["name"] == i["name"]:
            i["wins"] = current_player["wins"]
            i["losses"] = current_player["losses"]

    if current_player not in data['players']:
        data['players'].append(current_player)


    print("Current Scores:\n")
    for i in data['players']:

        print(i["name"], ": wins", i["wins"], " losses: ", i["losses"])

    with open('scores.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(data))
except:
    start_dict = {"players":[current_player]}
    with open('scores.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(start_dict))
    print("Current Scores:\n")
    for i in start_dict['players']:
        print(i["name"], ": wins", i["wins"], " losses: ", i["losses"])
#end added section
```

This will check if the current player exists in the JSON file, then add their scores to the current player dictionary.

At the end of the game, it will check to see if:

1. The file scores.json exists, and will create it if it doesn't.
2. The current player exists in the scores.JSON file, and will update their score if they do. If they don't it will add a new user to the JSON file.

Then will print the score list accordingly.
Careful though, if a username is misspelt in any way, a new user will be created.

You can also manually update the scores in the .json file, if desired.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I don't think it meets the requirement of a simple `.txt` file containing the winner names, right?

Comment: Yes, but I thought OP wanted a file with names and scores, so this method allows for adding/updating the scores of participants.

Comment: If i were doing this for myself, that would be a great way, however the brief unfortunately calls for using a text file specifically. Thank you though